# c++ class design, 'virtual options struct and setter'?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I'm not sure what to google or search for on this one, would this be a 'virtual member variable' or something of that sort. I have something like the below:

```
class ConcreteClass: public AbstractBaseclass {
public:
  struct Options {
     int x;
     string foo;
  };
  int options(int ac, char ** av, Options& opts) {
  // Declare the supported options.
  po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
  // ... etc, fill in with boost program options 
  }

  virtual void  MandatoryFunction1( ... ) { } 

  }
```

Different types of 'ConcreteClass' will have radically varying things in them ... seems silly to inherit Options from somewhere else as it would have to be an empty base struct.

Is there an intelligent way to mandate, via the 'AbstractBaseclass', that the derived class must declare some "Options" struct, and provide a function "options()" to fill it in? This is just to force some consistency with how the core library is being used in derived classes.

*Edit: it is OK if I need to edit the base class to support this. I'm thinking maybe have it contain a pure-virtual options() function, but I'm not sure what a good way is to have it accept a to-be-defined "Options" struct.

Comment: Can you make the Options struct a member of the base class?

Comment: If Options varies with the concrete classes, why not keep it private to them?  I can't see why you'd want to pass an Options object when calling your virtual `options()` function via a pointer-to-Base....  What would the generic code handling various concrete objects want with options specific to any of them?  If there is some reason, you could consider a `std::vector` or `map` of `std::string` or `boost::any`....

Comment: Here's a link to a specific code example, notice the nested "Options" class there:  

https://github.com/pkarasev3/nlmagick/blob/master/samples/affine_frame2frame.cpp

Maybe a base class of Options is really the way to go, then I can put those long lists of strings and what not into arrays and have the base do all the boost-program-options wrapping.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen a couple of this *how do I force people extending my class to do X* type of questions. The real question there is *why do you want to force it?* Do you *need* them to do it or you just *want* them to?

If you need them to implement that functionality, it means that some part of the code will actually *use* it, and if they don't implement it, the compiler will trigger an error and fail to compile, and your problem is solved without having to do anything.

If you just want them to, *rethink* your strategy. There is no point in forcing other's code to do something that is not needed. Maybe some extension to your class does not need *options* at all, why would they *have* to implement that function when they don't need them and you don't need them either?

Note that it is uncommon to find code (the exception is with templates) that depends on *any* `X::Options` struct implemented, as you will not be able to use that code *generically* --C++ uses static typing. So chances are that either you are not using that code *generically* or you need an `Options` interface. If you are using that in a template, the code will fail to compile the template, and you can even work out in the template how to produce a simple to read error message (think `static_assert`), if you are not using it the question stands: *why*?

Comment: How about this: the base class can have a pure virtual options(int ac, char* av, Options**) to parse CLI. It can also have a base Options struct with at least a 'verbose level' flag. Then client must a) inherit from Options and b) implement the parse function. Why do this: i'm getting too many subtly different ways of setting up these derived classes and confusing myself, let alone someone who doesn't know the math in the base class.

Comment: @peter: There is no need for the double pointer (that I think of right now), you can use a base `Options` object and force all deriving classes to also extend `Options`, but I don't think that is going to simplify the code. Depending on what the options actually are, you might be able to use a single `Options` type, or... well, at the end of the day the question still stands: why do you want to force you to do it? Just implement something that is simple, and you will use it. It is normal to change how you do it as you learn, maybe you can go back and refactor the old ways when you need to...

Answer (score 1):

Just follow 2 simple steps and you will get what you want:

(1) Make `options()` method pure `virtual` in `AbstractBaseclass`, so it will mandate every child `class` to implement it:

(2) Make `struct Options` inside `private` specifier under `AbstractBaseclass`. So, now every child `class` has to have its own `Options` to satisfy the `virtual options()` argument.

So overall your base `class` will look like:

```
class AbstractBaseclass {
  struct Options {};  // private
public:  // pure virtual 
  virtual int options(int ac, char ** av, Options& opts) = 0;
};
```

Comment: This will not work: As it is shown, the virtual method requires `AbstractBaseclass::Options&` as the third argument not `Derived::Options&`. The only way to make this work, is by having derived classes extend `AbstractBaseclass::Options` in their own version of `Options` (and probably some `dynamic_cast` trickery to try and downcast to the appropriate type), for that to work, the `Options` type in the abstract base will have to be accessible to extensions. And that will still leave the ugliness of `dynamic_cast`-ing in the code.

Comment: @David, it's a nice observation, but it compiles fine. I checked only till compilation part. I think, it should be working properly also.

Comment: What compiles? Have you tried extending the class, adding a `Derived::Options` type, implementing the virtual method and actually instantiating the derived type? I don't think so, as the `Options` type in the derived type will hide `AbstractBaseclass::Options` and the virtual function defined in the derived type will not *overwrite* the one in the base class (`AbstractBaseclass::Options` != `Derived::Options`), which means that the derived class is still abstract and not instantiable.

Comment: @David, you are correct, I didn't try instantiating object for `ConcreteClass`. It doesn't compile then.

Comment: Wouldn't that get handled by using a pointer to Options instead of by-reference? Its OK if so.